# Circular dependency with Terraform AWS EC2 / CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-code-deploy

## Question

How do I get a **re-built** *EC2 instance* to trigger a new *AWS CodeDeploy*?

**Note**: The problem is **NOT** the first deployment of the EC2 instances.  The problem happens when the *EC2 instances* are re-built and then re-deployed.

## Description

I am running into a chicken/egg scenario with an *AWS CodeDeploy* that is going to a set of EC2 instances.  The updates to elements of the *AWS AppSpec* are being re-deployed to the existing *EC2 instances*, as expected.
However, if I do changes that only rebuild the *EC2 instances*, and that do not cause any changes to the *AWS CodeDeploy*, when the *EC2 instances* come back up, and they finish re-initializing, the *AWS CodeDeploy* is **not** being re-applied to the new *EC2 instances*.

## Context

The infrastructure is being deployed via Terraform.

The *EC2 instances* take about 15 minutes to finish initializing.  So, any *AWS CodeDeploy* activity has to wait that 15 minutes before initiating anything on the EC2 instances.  Therefore, in the *AWS CodeDeploy* (see below) I put a `depends_on` a Terraform `time_sleep` resource, to wait for the *EC2 instances* to finish coming up, before attempting to do the actual *AWS CodeDeploy*.

### Terraform Pseudo-Code

```haskell
aws_instance "ec2_instance" {}
time_sleep "ec2_instance_delay" {
    create_duration = var.ec2_creation_delay
    triggers = {
        instance_arn = aws_instance.ec2_instance.arn
    }
}
template_dir {
    depends_on = [time_sleep.ec2_instance_delay]
    provisioner "local-element" {
        interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
        command     = <<EOC
true;
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_id=${};
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${};
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${};
aws deploy push --application-name ${aws_codedeploy_app.my_app.name} --description ${} --s3-location <s3-location> --source "${template_dir.appspec[count.index].destination_dir}";
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name <appName> --s3-location <s3 location> --deployment-group-name <group name>;
aws deploy wait deployment-successful --deployment-id $deploy_id;
EOC
    }
}
aws_codedeploy_app "my_app" {}
aws_codedeploy_deployment_group "my_app_group" {
    deployment_config_name = "CodeDeploymentDefault.AllAtOnce"
    ec2_tag_set {
        ec2_tag_filter {
            key   = "Name"
            type  = "KEY_AND_VALUE"
            value = aws_instance.ec2_instance.tags["Name]
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: TTBOMK, Terraform doesn't have an `aws_codedeploy_deployment` resource.  To workaround this, I am using a `template_dir` `appspec`, combined with a `provisioner "local-exec"` to generate the actual deployment. This ends up  producing a command-line similar to ...

```bash
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name <appName> --s3-location <s3 location> --deployment-group-name <group name>
```

That is working as intended.  Any changes to the deployment scripts, or to the *AppSpec.yml* file are properly staged to S3 and subsequently re-deployed to the existing *EC2 instances*.
However, if I have to do changes to **just** the EC2 instance, such as changes to the `userdata`, the *EC2 instances* rebuild properly, but the *AWS CodeDeploy* is not re-applied to the rebuilt *EC2 instances*.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to use `codedeploy` ?

Comment: The primary purpose of this deployment was to create an example of using a Cookie-Cutter (see https://pypi.org/project/cookiecutter/) that our team had created, for using AWS CodeDeploy in a highly-constrained business/technical environment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be much easier than I thought.

Embed the `id` of the `time_sleep` resource in a comment, in the `appspec.yml` file.  This `id` will get populated during the `local-exec` execution.

Then, in the `template_dir` resource, change the explicit `depends_on = time_sleep.ec2_instance_delay]` to an implicit dependency on the `id` of the`time_sleep` resource, using the `vars` argument of the `template_dir` resource.

Since the `time_sleep` resource triggers on the `EC2 instance.arn`, it will get regenerated whenever the `ec2_instance.arn` changes.  This will cause the `local-exec` to regenerate, stage and redeploy to all the *EC2 instances* that have the appropriate, matching tags.

**FYI**: The value of the `time_sleep.id`, is a time-stamp.

## Code

`appspec.yml`

```hs
# ${time_stamp}
```

`main.tf`

```hs
template_dir {
   // Replace explicit dependency with an implicit dependency
   vars = merge({
       time_stamp = time_sleep.ec2_instance_delay.id
   })
...
}
```